# How to stream raw frames from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to server iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, videochat

I have to implement video calling application, for that I need to capture raw frames from `AVCaptureViewDataOutput` and send it to server. I don't know how to do that and what type of streaming is required?

Comment: did you find anything about this?? I'm in the same situation and COMPLETELY lost!